# I am trying to convert a string of words into an array with the spaces included

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, spaces

I want the user to input a name an actor: tom hanks

I am trying to convert the string "tom hanks" into an array.

However I want to keep the space in between the "m" and "t". so the array would read:

{"t","o", "m", " ", "h", "a", "n", "k", "s"}

Then the users input is compared against the answer in the program. letter by letter.

Considering the user will input a space, I am going to convert the string name into arrays and compare them like for like, with the space and all.

Here is the code i have so far

```
    String x;

    System.out.println("Please input a name");
    x = input.next(); 

    //the user enters in "tom hanks"

    String[] a = x.split("\\b");
```

This will only create the array {"t", "o", "m"}

Any help would be much appreciated it, thank you in advance.

Comment: Java I presume? (looks like it, but there are several languages that can call the java libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an empty string as the regex expression to split the string:

```
String str = "alan smith";
String[] letters = str.split("");
```

For example:

```
String str = "alan smith";
String[] letters = str.split("");
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
    System.out.print(letters[i] + " ");
```

Output:

```
a l a n   s m i t h
```

**EDIT**:

It seems that this method generate an empty token at the beginning.

Comment: for me this is only print out the: a l a n

Comment: It seems that the problem is the way you are reading the text: change `x = input.next();` with `x = input.readLine();`

Comment: sorry i am just kind of new to java. do i have to change anything else, as the readLine is saying its undefined.

Comment: you were right, the input only read the first part of the name.

so it never even converted " hanks" into an array.
With readLine, it read in the space using the char array!!

Answer (score 3):

You should convert your string to character array instead

```
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

You can access it like a normal array.

Comment: because the user is entering the string, it only seems to read the first word.